# Linq Join To View Without Materializing Until Filtered

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, view

So I'm using EF and I have a view in my database that has way too many records to bring into memory in my C# program.  During runtime I am able to get a list of IDs that I want to filter the view by that I load into an IEnumerable.

Now I want to get back only the records in the view that have the IDs in the IEnumerable.  Using Linq I write:

```
for v in view
join i in IDs on v.ID equals i.ID
select v
```

However, this first tries to materialize the view and then do the filtering in memory which is way too slow.  Is there a way for me in Linq to push the filtering to the database so that the join occurs in SQL Server?

I know I could just create a sproc and have a TVP with the IDs and use ADO.NET to make it all happen on the database side but I was curious if there is a way to do this with EF and Linq.

Comment: You can add a `where` statement in linq. What are you trying to filter by?

Answer (score 1):

If your list of IDs is of reasonable size, you can use where, and EF translates "Contains" to:

WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4....)

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

for v in view
where ids.Contains(v.ID)
select v
```